# Regarding DateTime Format "%h:%m:%s" allowing hour as "00"

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a TextBox to enter time in the format `"%h:%m:%s"`.
The allowed time inputs:

> 01:20:00
>
> 12:20:00

I am converting the string taken from TextBox using:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("00:20:00", "%h:%m:%s",
                       culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out newData);
```

But above code converts hour `00` to `12` when providing the data through newData. I want to throw error in this case. Please provide your inputs.

Comment: What is `culture` exactly?

Comment: There is no point to use single custom format specifiers (`%`) in this case since _they are not single_. What do you mean by _converts_ by the way? Could you please be more specific? It is not clear what you try to do.

Comment: Why not just check the characters of the string up to the first ":"?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you should try to parse to a `TimeSpan` instead of `DateTime`.

Use the following `string.Format` pattern to convert to a `TimeSpan`:

```
var pattern = @"hh\:mm\:ss";
```

see MSDN for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx

***UPDATED***

Working Sample code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime newData;
            TimeSpan newSpan;

            DateTime.TryParseExact("00:20:00", "%h:%m:%s",
                   CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out newData);

            Console.WriteLine(newData);
            // 8/5/2014 12:20:00 AM

            TimeSpan.TryParseExact("00:20:00", @"hh\:mm\:ss",
                   CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture, TimeSpanStyles.None, out newSpan);

            Console.WriteLine(newSpan);
            // 00:20:00

            Console.WriteLine(newSpan.Hours);
            // 0 

            Console.WriteLine(newSpan.TotalHours);
            // 0.33~


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As per MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx
"h" - The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 1 to 12.
"hh" - The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12.

I am having doubts why it is allowing "00".

Answer (score 1):

You should be using upper-case "H" for 24-hour time.

Comment: I need it in the 12 hour format as per requirement.

Comment: Yeah in 12 hour format, dotnet allows 00 to be treated as 12. But It should not be allowed in my specification. Its an exceptional case, where I should not allow "00" to be converted to 12. So I need some ways to change this behaviour of DateTime format of dotnet to not to allow "00".

Comment: You can't stop it.  Any valid value will be parsed successfully.  All you can do is validate the `DateTime` afterwards to ensure that it falls within the allowable range.  By using 24-hour time, you ensure that anything beginning with "00" will be considered 12 AM and anything with "12" will be considered 12 PM, allowing you to determine whether the original value was valid based on your own business rules.